# Angular components overflowing bounding flex-box

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a component with two flex columns with a set height of 100vh. In the left table I have a multiple divs with just a min-height so they will adjust to the bounding divs and using *overflow-y: auto* when necessary.

Left:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 flex-column">
    <div class="card flex-card">
        <!---- some content ---!>
    </div>
    <div class="card flex-card">
        <!---- table and such ---!>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the right column I have two nested components. Within these components I have used the same classes so they will also fit within the right columns bounds.

Right:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 flex-column">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item">
      <component1></component1>
      <br />
      <component2></component2>
    </ng-container>
 </div>
```

For some reason the components in the right column overflow the container and stretches past the view height. What can I do to make the components conform to the set height in the main page? Does it have to do with the conditional on the *ng-container*?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem or error you're having, ideally in an online code editor like [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: I believe in order for this to work you'll need to give `component1` and `component2` a max height aswell.

Comment: @Cuzy This is the solution I was hoping to avoid and instead having the components automatically adjust to fill up the column height.